# Difficulty grasping Functional Dependency concepts with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, functional-dependencies

I can write queries fairly well, but basic Database Design concepts continue to frustrate me :/ I'm working through an old book to try and brush up on the material, but functional dependencies are really making my head spin. For instance, the following question:

Assume that Marcia keeps a table of data about her customers. Consider just the following part of that table:
CUSTOMER(Phone, FirstName, LastName)
Explain the conditions under which each of the following are true:

1. Phone --> (FirstName, LastName)
2. (Phone, FirstName) --> LastName
3. (Phone, LastName) --> First Name
4. (LastName, FirstName) --> Phone
5. Phone --> --> LastName
6. Phone --> --> FirstName
7. Phone --> --> (FirstName, LastName)

I don't even understand how to go about answering the question!..

Comment: The question to ask yourself is: if you know the value of the left-hand side, is there only one possible value for the right-hand side. Example: Phone --> (FirstName, LastName). In English this would be: given a Phone number, there is only one possible First name plus Last name combination. So... for the question, explain the conditions under which that would be true.

Comment: Thanks Darius! I think I'm starting to get it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Db design, but from what I understand:

And assuming that Phone is unique.

1. True. Because a Client's's FirstName and Last Name can be uniquely determined from their Phone
2. True.
3. True
4. False

The double narrow I dont know what it is mean

Comment: A friend of mine sent the following: http://www.docstoc.com/docs/145173736/Normalization2-Fall05-Answers. The matter is to state what has to occur precisely for each statement to be TRUE.

Comment: very good explanation in that pdf, how i post 1,2,3 are true assuming that phone is unique